# Organic Groups Permissions and Site-wide Roles

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

I currently have a Drupal 6 site set up using Organic Groups and OG User Roles. This is important because we have mainly public groups, however some pages in the groups are restricted by a user's role, such as staff or student. In this way, a page can be private to its group members, and additionally visible by those users who have the staff or student role.

OG User Roles has not been upgraded to Drupal 7 and we are attempting to find a replacement. OG 7 does provide integrated roles for groups, BUT it does not include the ability to set viewership based on these roles. Public / Private is too black and white, we need much more granular settings for our editors.

I have looked at Content Access, but we have about 20 roles on our site, and our editors would be overwhelmed by the options. Additionally, Content Access does not provide a way to prevent an editor from assigning "edit" or "delete" permissions, which is an issue for us.

We only want editors to be able to say "For this group page, this site-wide role can see this page." Very similar to the existent OG audience selection, but including site-wide rules as OG User Roles does currently in D6.

Is there any solution for this in D7 with Organic Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this we had to use an additional content access module, and we picked [Simple Access](http://drupal.org/project/simple_access).

Using the OG user roles built into OG for D7 we got our editing permissions under control, but that did not allow us to control *viewership* permissions for the content at all.

By utilizing Simple Access in addition to OG, we have the solution that we needed.

Comment: Did you try using the built-in OG Access Control module (the one that comes with OG).  It's a real pain to set up but it does control viewership permissions for the content.

Comment: @JenLampton At the time this question was written, OG Access control only provided public / private setting for *everyone* on the site. We could not assign viewership based on a user's role. In our use case we had several "levels" of content for students, staff, public, etc. and OG Access Control did not do that a year ago. If it does now, that's great, though.